# How can access to settings of a public router be (mis)used?

Tags: router

I've noticed that, in the local café, Wi-Fi router credentials are simply user: `admin` pass: `admin` (as default). Upon this discovery, I was intrigued and I wanted to know more about **what possibilities do you have when you have the access to router settings**. Not that I would want to anything serious, I just want to know more about router security (to protect myself also)... mind that the router is not aftermarket one, but the cheap one you get with your contract, so it doesn't have many advanced options...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a brief list of some fun possibilities:

- Hog all off the WiFi Connection by kicking everyone off. Kick everyone else off in a number of ways, changing password to WiFi and to the router to prevent wired users, then block everyone but your MAC address. I wouldn't suggest this though because the owners may notice a lack of wireless internet and go and reset it.
- Provide a captive portal page that looks like Google to steal credentials
- Provide a captive portal page that take you to a drive by or provides a hook
- Set all DNS traffic to a DNS server you control to point all bank traffic to spoofed banks to harvest credentials.
- If a remote firmware update is available then have malicious firmware updated to allow a whole set of Man in the Middle attacks to happen
- Logging all packets coming in and through, pick up unencrypted traffic*

These are just a few I can think of off the top of my head
*Probably can't be done without flashing firmware or a more advanced router